# Silverlight disappears when opening chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight, developer-tools

I recently upgraded Chrome (version 38.0.2125.104) and now any time I open developer tools on a page with a silverlight object, silverlight disappears. It doesn't crash, it is just gone. As long as I don't open developer tools it runs fine, but as soon as I open developer tools it's gone.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a chrome issue or an issue with silverlight?

Comment: I've seen this too, but after much searching, I still have no idea what's going on here. I don't think that the silverlight app is absent, just unrendered.

Comment: I have the same issue. every time I open the dev tool up, Silverlight object become blank. Object is still sitting there but it doesn't render the content.

Comment: I've noticed that if you close the developer tools and reposition the browser window, silverlight comes back in exactly the same state it was in, confirming that it's still there, just not rendered. This is baffling me. I've resorted to firefox for the time being.

Comment: there is an issue for this but it is still in unconfimed state ... https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342684

Comment: I think this question is now out of date, as of Chrome 42 NPAPI plugins like silverlight will no longer work in Chrome and thus are completely in-accessible.

Answer (score -1):

41.0.2272.118m not be a problem with the Google Chrome version.

the new beta version 42.0.2311.90 m or ask for it quits

https://www.google.com/intl/tr/chrome/browser/beta.html exchange does not function normally if the beta version

Browser address bar chrome://flags/#enable-NPAPI summer press ENTER. Then enable the disabled to find the NPAPI year.

exit and re-enter without completely delete history in Google Chrome. Problems must be improved.

image : [enter link description here](http://dogalsifarehberi.com/filepath/disyayin/npapi.png)