# Silverlight dissapears as soon as Chrome console is open

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, silverlight

I have an application hosted on a IIS server, whose index ASPX page contains a Silverlight app, declared like this :

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="border:2px solid #6D7788;">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            id="silverlightControl" width="100%" height="100%">
            [...]
```

The silverlight controller runs fine, until I open the Chrome Dev Console (F12).
When I do so, the silverlight controller turns into a blank white area.

This issue occurs only in Chrome (v. 39.0.2171.95 m).

I'm looking for any sort of clue regarding this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Chrome [has disabled all NPAPI plugins in Chrome 42 and will be removed entirely in Chrome 45 in September](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation). You're probably better of replacing whatever it is, than trying to make it work for a few more months. Also, your Chrome is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a solution other than using a different browser, but there is an open bug for it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342684

Also a related question (where I fould the open bug):
[Silverlight disappears when opening chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613658/silverlight-disappears-when-opening-chrome-developer-tools?rq=1)